# Why does PowerShell mangle non-ASCII characters in scraped HTML?

Tags: encoding, web-scraping, powershell-3.0

I'm collecting airport information from Wikipedia. I want to preserve the non-ASCII characters in the airport names.

In a web browser the [airports whose codes begin with Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_code:_Z) look like this:

[image]

Airport DBE is called "Doln**í** Benesov Airport". Airport ZBK is called "**Ž**abljak Airport". I expect the same values in my output.

I'm scraping the data with a function like this:

```
function Get-Airports ($Uri) {
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing |
  Select-Xml -XPath '//table/tr[td]' |
  % {
    $Kids = $_.Node.ChildNodes
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      Iata = $Kids[0].InnerText
      Icao = $Kids[1].InnerText
      AirportName = $Kids[2].InnerText
      LocationServed = $Kids[3].InnerText
    }
  }
}
```

The function fetches the given URI, implicitly converts the HTML response to XML, extracts the table data rows using XPath, then maps each column value to a property of a new PowerShell object.

To fetch all the airports beginning with Z, I use a command like this:

```
$Airports = Get-Airports 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_code:_Z'
```

The `$Airports` variable contains a collection of the new PowerShell objects, one for each data row in the table.

This command shows that the scraper mangles names containing non-ASCII characters:

```
$Airports |
? { $_.AirportName -like '*[?]*' } |
Format-Table
```

None of the airport names should contain question marks. I expect this command to produce no output.

Instead, there are several objects with two question marks in their names where a non-ASCII character would appear in the web browser:

```
Iata  Icao   AirportName                              LocationServed                                               
----  ----   -----------                              --------------                                               
ZBE   LKZA   Doln?? Benesov Airport                   Z??b??eh, Czech Republic                                     
ZBK          ??abljak Airport                         ??abljak, Montenegro                                         
ZBM   CZBM   Bromont (Roland D??sourdy) Airport       Bromont, Quebec, Canada                                      
ZLG          La G??era Airport                        La G??era, Western Sahara                                    
ZLT          La Tabati??re Airport (TC: CTU5)         La Tabati??re, Quebec, Canada                                
ZOS   SCJO   Ca??al Bajo Carlos Hott Siebert Airport  Osorno, Chile                                                
ZPC   SCPC   Puc??n Airport                           Puc??n, Chile                                                
ZQW   EDRZ   Zweibr??cken Airport                     Zweibr??cken, Germany                                        
ZTB          T??te-??-la-Baleine Airport (TC: CTB6)   T??te-??-la-Baleine, Quebec, Canada
```

It's a character encoding issue for sure. Wikipedia produces [UTF-8](http://www.utf-8.com/), but it looks like PowerShell is decoding it as [Windows-1252](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305145.aspx) or some other single-byte character set.

I can't find a switch on the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) cmdlet or the [Select-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx) cmdlet that would let me specify UTF-8.

Is there a succinct way to solve this problem? Any way would do, but I think there is a simple thing I'm missing.

Comment: Rather using the defaults you may need to use the underlying .NET types and methods to 1. treat the result of the web request as a byte sequence, 2. use the HTTP response header to determine the encoding and 3. use that encoding to convert to a string before parsing as XML. (Ie. I assume there is no `<?xml>` header specifying an encoding and thus the encoding is not passed in the string to `Select-XML` so that defaults...

Comment: @Richard Oh dear, I hope not. Might as well pick up C#.

Comment: @Richard It's a C# problem after all, but not one I can easily fix! See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19256210/111424).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short Answer: Use the Content property

In Get-Airports replace the start of the pipeline with this expression:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

And the function will produce the expected result.

There will be no airport names with question marks.

#### Long answer: Invoke-WebRequest is faulty

Invoke-WebRequest returns an instance of [BasicHtmlWebResponseObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.basichtmlwebresponseobject.content%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Its ToString method mangles the response content.

The Chinese airport list is full of non-ASCII characters so provides a good test case. This code scrapes that page and extracts the title via the Content property and the ToString method:

```
$uri = 'http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/國際民航組織機場代碼_(Z)'
$response = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing)
$pattern = '\<title\>.+\</title\>'
[Regex]::Match($response.Content, $pattern).Value
[Regex]::Match($response.ToString(), $pattern).Value
```

The output looks like this:

```
<title>國際民航組織機場代碼 (Z) - 维基百科，自由的百科全书</title>
<title>?????????????????????????????? (Z) - ????????????????????????????????????</title>
```

The [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.basichtmlwebresponseobject.content%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property contains the properly-decoded response.

The [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method returns garbage.

It's seems reasonable for ToString to behave like Content, so there seems to be a problem here.

To dig further, I used [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), the open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler.

The BasicHtmlWebResponseObject constructor calls InitializeContent to set the Content property:

```
// Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.BasicHtmlWebResponseObject
private void InitializeContent()
{
    string contentType = ContentHelper.GetContentType(base.BaseResponse);
    if (ContentHelper.IsText(contentType))
    {
        string characterSet = WebResponseHelper.GetCharacterSet(base.BaseResponse);
        this.Content = StreamHelper.DecodeStream(base.RawContentStream, characterSet);
        return;
    }
    this.Content = string.Empty;
}
```

The method awesomatically detects the correct decoding.

BasicHtmlWebResponseObject iherits ToString from WebResponseObject:

```
// Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject
public sealed override string ToString()
{
    char[] chars = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(this.Content);
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!this.IsPrintable(chars[i]))
        {
            chars[i] = '.';
        }
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

WebResponseObject's ToString method naively decodes the response as ASCII.

The default [ASCII decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx) uses replacement fallback to produce question marks for unknown bytes.

I don't see it documented anywehere, but I think Select-Xml calls ToString to convert pipeline objects to XML. It's reasonable behavior, but doesn't work here because of a mistake in BasicHtmlWebResponseObject's design.

I guessed at a Windows-1252 decoding because it's my default code page. It couldn't be though; the character `í` has an encoding in Windows-1252, but it's replaced by `?` in the output.

Comment: Issue raised on Microsoft Connect: [Invoke-WebRequest mangles non-ASCII characters (BasicHtmlWebResponseObject)](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/804865/invoke-webrequest-mangles-non-ascii-characters-basichtmlwebresponseobject#)